# How to convert java.util.date to required format in scriptlet

Tags: java, jsp, date, scriptlet

I have a transfer object being returned to the JSP after a search. It is having a `java.util.Date` field (e.g. `private Date issueDate;`)

I am accessing the data in TO using `usebean` tag and displaying the date as:

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" readonly="readonly" NAME="issueDt" ID="issueDt" 
       SIZE="45" value="<%=mySearchTO.getIssueDt()%>">
```

However, this is printing the date in the format say for e.g. **MON JAN 31 00:08:00 IST 2011**

I want the date to be printed simply as `MM/DD/YYYY` and in the cases where time is also important, in the `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM` format.

How to achieve this inside JSP? I don't know if I need to go for Javascript function or some static Java method.

Please excuse the usage of scriptlet. It's a legacy application and so I can not use EL. 
Please provide solution through scriptlet only. So solutions like:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${new Date(c.dateInIntegerValue)}" 
                pattern="dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm"/>
```

available in other questions, will not work for me.

Is the following code valid?

```
<fmt:formatDate value="<%=mySearchTO.getIssueDt()%>" 
                pattern="dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm"/>
```

If yes, how to use it in the JSP? I mean label and all!

Also as far as possible, I want to avoid usage of jquery and such libraries.

Comment: Why can't you use EL and JSTL? What's your version of jsp-api? Name your servlet container and version as well.

Comment: There are 100's of legacy JSP pages with scriptlets in the application. So I don't want to introduce EL in just one page where I want change and disturb the "sanity" of the legacy app :)

Comment: Are you using custom tag libraries? Maybe you could put your code over there? Does your project have any files ending in `.tld`?

Comment: no.. no files ending in .tld...

Comment: It's **not different** from how you do it in a normal Java class. Asking this question in JSP/Scriptlet context is basically irrelevant. Just ask it in the future in Java context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>    
<% SimpleDateFormat dateFormatWithTime = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");%>
<INPUT TYPE="text" readonly="readonly" NAME="issueDt" ID="issueDt" SIZE="45" value="<%=dateFormatWithTime.format(mySearchTO.getIssueDt())%>">
```

Ideally you should just use [`formatDate`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatDate.html) from JSTL or factor out this code into a
custom taglib.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` class or [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Use DateFormat

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat();
df.applyPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
System.out.println(df.format(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ..

DateFormat f = new  SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
.