# Convert Epoch Time to a date format in JSP

Tags: jsp, date-format, epoch

Please let me know how do I  convert Epoch Time (example -  1355893200000) to mm/dd hh:mm AM/PM format in JSP.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1 (three `startDate` keep same):

```
<jsp:useBean id="startDate" class="java.util.Date" />

<jsp:setProperty name="startDate" property="time" value="${record.startDate}"/>

<fmt:formatDate value="${startDate}" type="date" dateStyle="long"/>
```

Solution 2:

```
// item is long, don't pass testing, is EL support Date Type init Object??

<fmt:formatDate value="${Date(item)}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"/>
```

`fmt:parseDate` use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse Date from String.
a `Date` could construct from `Date date = new Date (Long.parase(epochString))`

The JSP version usually goes hand in hand with the servlet version as follows:

```
Servlet 2.5 uses JSP 2.1 
Servlet 2.4 uses JSP 2.0 
Servlet 2.3 uses JSP 1.2 
Servlet 2.2 uses JSP 1.1 
Servlet 2.1 uses JSP 1.0
```

maybe help:

- [java - Converting Epoch Time String to Date String in JSP - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515429/converting-epoch-time-string-to-date-string-in-jsp)
- [jsp - Is it possible to create a date value in Expression Language? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512682/is-it-possible-to-create-a-date-value-in-expression-language)
- [java - Format a date and display it using JSTL and EL - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823033/format-a-date-and-display-it-using-jstl-and-el?rq=1)
- [how to know which servlet and jsp version (OCPJWCD forum at Coderanch)](https://coderanch.com/t/425693/certification/servlet-jsp-version)
- [jsp - How to convert java.util.date to required format in scriptlet - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193617/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-required-format-in-scriptlet?rq=1)
- [JSTL Core  Tag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatdate_tag.htm)

reference:

[jstl code repo](https://github.com/javaee/jstl-api)

Answer (score 0):

You could use JSTL Core `fmt:formatDate` Tag. More info http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatdate_tag.htm

Comment: does fmt:formatDate format epoch time ? It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: You could do something like this
<c:set var="now" value="<%=new java.util.Date(epocStamo)%>" />
<fmt:formatDate type="date" value="${now}" />

Answer (score -1):

You can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371326/java-date-from-unix-timestamp) for converting a unix timestamp to a Java `Date` object.

To format the date you can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

E.g.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd hh:mm aaa");
String formatted = format.parse(myDate);
```

Comment: I want to use JSTL tags only