# Converting Epoch Time String to Date String in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, date, jstl

I am getting the Epoch time data as `1376493600` (String).
I want to convert it into Human Readable/Normal Date String `(dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss)` format

```
<fmt:parseDate value="${record.attributes.P_Close_Time}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" var="date" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${date}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
```

`But I am getting Unparsable Date error in the fmt:parseDate line.`

How to convert the epoc time to readable date format as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do this in your controller by converting the string to an integer then load it into a Date object?

```
date = new Date(Integer.valueOf(timeData)*1000);
```

Then you can format that Date object however you like.

Comment: Sorry the response is directly from URL in JSON. SO can't convert in controller

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Date date = new Date (Long.parase(epochString)); 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(String pattern);
String formatted  = sdf.forms(date);
```

Comment: please post JSP. not Java

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 package naveed.workingfiles;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;

public class TimestampToDate {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(Long.parseLong("1376493600"));
          Date date = new Date(stamp.getTime());
          System.out.println(date);

    }

    }
```

Comment: please post in JSP and not in Java backend